# can't read data from database in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am learning asp.net using vb,i am working on college assignment 
i have to read data from msaccess and show record in label
basically i am doing 'search' operation

here is the code

Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim sname, lname, city, subj, gender, hobbies, religion As String
    Dim age, phone As Integer

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\himzz\Documents\Database1.accdb;")
    connection.Open()

    If Not IsPostBack Then


    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    sname = TextBox1.Text
    lname = TextBox2.Text
    age = TextBox3.Text
    city = TextBox4.Text
    phone = TextBox5.Text
    subj = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        gender = "male"
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        gender = "female"
    Else
        gender = "other"
    End If

    'If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked Then
    '    hobbies = "cricket swimming tennis "
    'End If

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        hobbies += "cricket "
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        hobbies += "swimming "
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        hobbies += " tennis "
    End If

    religion = DropDownList2.SelectedValue



    Try
        Dim q As String = "insert into stud (sname,lname,age,city,phone,subj,gender,hobbies,religion) values('" & sname & "','" & lname & "','" & age & "','" & city & "','" & phone & "','" & subj & "','" & gender & "','" & hobbies & "','" & religion & "' )"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, connection)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("submitted")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)

End Sub

Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click



    Dim q As String = "select lname from stud where sname='" & sname & "' "
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, connection)
    Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()




    While reader.Read()
(tried this but not worked)  ' Label12.Text = " " & reader("sname")
```

(tried this also but not worked)' Label12.Text =reader.Item("sname").ToString()
(not working)      Label12.Text = reader("sname").ToString

```
        'Label13.Text = "age " & reader("age")
        'Label14.Text = "city " & reader("city")
        'Label15.Text = "phone no " & reader("phone")
        'Label16.Text = "subject " & reader("subj")
        'Label17.Text = "Gedner " & reader("gender")
        'Label18.Text = "Hobbies " & reader("hobbies")
        'Label19.Text = "Religion " & reader("religion")


    End While

    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: when i click on search....nothing happens

Comment: You can't use `MsgBox` in ASP.Net.  And your `Response.Redirect` makes no sense.

Comment: am using MS access

Comment: i am using asp.net using vb.net and response.redirect is for clearing the control after clicking on button

Comment: Looks like Button4 is your search button. Under Button4_Click event replace sname with TextBox1.Text and try.

Comment: In Button 4 Click your select asks for only lname. There is no sname column in the reader.